# Data management in a parallel for-loop in Julia

Tags: for-loop, parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to do some statistical analysis using Julia. The code consists of the files `script.jl` (e.g. initialisation of the data) and `algorithm.jl`.

The number of simulations is large (at least 100,000) so it makes sense to use parallel processing.

The code below is just some pseudocode to illustrate my question —

```
function script(simulations::Int64)

# initialise input data
...

# initialise other variables for statistical analysis using zeros()
...

require("algorithm.jl")

@parallel for z = 1:simulations
  while true

    choices = algorithm(data);      

    if length(choices) == 0
      break
    else
      # process choices and pick one (which alters the data)
      ...
    end

  end
end

# display results of statistical analysis
...

end
```

and

```
function algorithm(data)

# actual algorithm
...

return choices;

end
```

As example, I would like to know how many choices there are on average, what is the most common choice, and so on. For this purpose I need to save some data from `choices` (*in* the for-loop) to the statistical analysis variables (initialised *before* the for-loop) and display the results (*after* the for-loop).

I've read about using `@spawn` and `fetch()` and functions like `pmap()` but I'm not sure how I should proceed. Just using the variables inside the for-loop does not work as each proc gets its own copy, so the values of the statistical analysis variables after the for-loop will just be zeros.

**[Edit]** In Julia I use `include("script.jl")` and `script(100000)` to run the simulations, there are no issues when using a single proc. However, when using multiple procs (e.g. using `addprocs(3)`) all statistical variables are zeros after the for-loop — which is to be expected.

Comment: Does your `algorithm` function always return identical `choices` for identical `data` input?

Comment: @rickhg12hs Yes it does.

Comment: Then given your pseudo-code, wouldn't only the first loop (`z = 1`) process any `choices`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to parallelize an inherently serial operations, because each operation is related to the result of another one (in this case `data`).
I think if you could implement the above code like:

```
@parallel (dosumethingwithdata) for z = 1:simulations
  while true

    choices = algorithm(data,z);      

    if length(choices) == 0
      break
    else
      # process choices and pick one (which alters the data)
      ...
    end

    data

  end
end
```

then you may find a parallel solution for the problem.